# How to get Phpunit Test Summary

Tags: shell, phpunit

Im currently working on a Phpunit test and i was wondering if is it possible to get the Test Summary and store it to a variable so i can send it via Email?.

```
Time: 11.92 minutes, Memory: 20.00Mb

There were 4 failures:

1) BingTestTool::testPushCampaign_without_status
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-''
+'Active'
```

Here is the result that phpunit outputs in the console, can i store this to a variable? so that i can send it tru email after the test run

Answer (score 1):

If you run `phpunit` in your console then just pipe its output to `mail`:

```
$ phpunit | mail test@example.org -s 'Results of phpunit'
```

The `-s` command line argument allows setting the email's `Subject`.

---

If the execution of `phpunit` is just a step of a longer process (a deployment, for example) and you need the output for some processing, you can enclose the `phpunit` command into backquotes (``` `` ```) or `$()` and use the expression as the right-hand side of an assignment:

```
RESULT="`phpunit`"
```

or

```
RESULT="$(phpunit)"
```

The double quotes around the expression are needed to keep the output (which is a multi-line string) as a single word and prevent the shell from interpreting it. There must be no spaces around the equal sign.

Now you can display it:

```
echo "$RESULT"
```

or pipe it to the input of various Unix programs. For example:

```
echo "$RESULT" | grep '^Time:' | cut -f1 -d,
```

feeds the content of variable `$RESULT` to `grep` that extracts and outputs only the line that starts with `Time:`; the output of `grep` is piped then to `cut` to keep only the first column using `,` as delimiter.

Comment: I need the Results in a variable i have something to do to it, is there a way to get it?

Comment: I am confused on how will i use it, can you provide an example in which the result is stored in a variable?

Comment: The value of a variable is accessed by prefixing the name of the variable with a dollar sign (`$`). See the updated answer.

Comment: The RESULT = "$(phpunit)"; gives an syntax error, im planning to get the phpunit test result in the teardownafterclass function then send it in a email